# Query returning multiple identical rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is returning multiple rows with an identical column, i don;t know where these extra columns are coming from.

```
select AccountNum,voucher  into #temp from LEDGERTRANS join CUSTINVOICETABLE on CUSTINVOICETABLE.INVOICEID = LedgerTrans.voucher
```

returns

```
AccountNum    Voucher
110100        mCR1
400850        mCR1
515000        mCR1
409000        mCR1
```

Which is cool, because they each represent different dollar amounts.
However, when i run the main query:

```
    SELECT distinct
    NAME AS 'Customer',
    ORDERACCOUNT AS 'Acct #',
    '' AS 'Sales Order',
    INVOICEDATE AS 'Date',
    INVOICEID AS 'Invoice',
    CUSTINVOICELINE.AMOUNTCUR AS 'Inv Amt',
    '' AS 'Itemid',
    (CASE CREDITREASON WHEN 1 THEN 'Other'
                       WHEN 2 THEN 'Damaged'
                       WHEN 3 THEN 'Order Entry'
                       WHEN 4 THEN 'Outside Service'
                       WHEN 5 THEN 'Pricing'
                       WHEN 6 THEN 'Quality'
                       WHEN 7 THEN 'Rework'
                       WHEN 8 THEN 'Ruined & Lost' 
                       WHEN 9 THEN 'Sales Agreement'
                       WHEN 10 THEN 'Freight'
                       WHEN 11 THEN 'Quanity'
                       WHEN 12 THEN 'Customer Service'
                       ELSE 'None' END) AS 'Reason',
    dbo.DIMENSIONS.DESCRIPTION AS 'Division',
    CUSTINVOICETABLE.CREATEDBY,
    null as 'CreatedDate',

    #temp.AccountNum + ' ' + LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME As 'Account'
    --#temp1.Dimension as 'Department'

FROM
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETABLE INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUSTINVOICELINE ON dbo.CUSTINVOICETABLE.RECID = PARENTRECID INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DIMENSIONS ON NUM = dbo.CUSTINVOICETABLE.DIMENSION2_
    join #temp on Custinvoicetable.InvoiceID = #temp.voucher
    left JOIN LEDGERTABLE on LEDGERTABLE.AccountNum = #temp.AccountNum
WHERE
    dbo.CUSTINVOICELINE.DIMENSION2_ IN ('23')
    AND
    (INVOICEID LIKE 'MCR-%'
    OR
    INVOICEID LIKE 'MIV-%')
    AND
    INVOICEDATE BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014'
    AND
    CREATEDBY IN ('clk')
AND LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME NOT Like ('%Accounts Receivable%')
```

it will return multiple identical results for the dollar amounts that include code account nums not included in that table. This is found in the last column (which are account codes along with some concatenated verbiage) What am I doing wrong?

```
Schaller Corporation    112523      2014-01-24 00:00:00.000 MCR-00005142    -250.000000000000       Other   Stephens Road-Detroit   clk NULL    400850 Sales-Washing
Schaller Corporation    112523      2014-01-24 00:00:00.000 MCR-00005142    -250.000000000000       Other   Stephens Road-Detroit   clk NULL    409000 Sales-Ruined & Lost
Schaller Corporation    112523      2014-01-24 00:00:00.000 MCR-00005142    -250.000000000000       Other   Stephens Road-Detroit   clk NULL    515000 Outside Services
```

Comment: what is wrong about that? you're selecting the column from the other joined table.

Comment: If you look at the results, they are not identical.  The last 2 columns are distinct.

Comment: You are joining `#temp` with `on Custinvoicetable.InvoiceID = #temp.voucher` and this apparently returns multiple rows per id. didn't you for example need to also join on `and Custinvoicetable.ORDERACCOUNT = #temp.AccountNum`?

Comment: They are distinct in that field, but have the same dollar amounts, when they shouldn't. the three repeat the same dollar amount, i don't know where these are coming from in the query as far as looping though and bringing these in

Comment: If any column in a row is different - DISTINCT will list it. It only filters out where the entire row is identical.

Comment: What you're try to accomplish isn't clear enough. You may have insufficient join criteria to #temp or you may want to do an Inner Join between #temp and LEDGERTABLE in a subquery and Left Join to the results of that or something different entirely. Without the understanding of what you're trying to accomplish it isn't really possible to fix your query to do what you want. Personally based upon what I'm seeing I think you should scrap #temp entirely and put LEDGERTRANS in its place in the main query. This will eliminate the many to one and still give you the desired join.